# How to get JSON from webpage into Python script

Tags: python, json

Got the following code in one of my scripts:

```
#
# url is defined above.
#
jsonurl = urlopen(url)

#
# While trying to debug, I put this in:
#
print jsonurl

#
# Was hoping text would contain the actual json crap from the URL, but seems not...
#
text = json.loads(jsonurl)
print text
```

What I want to do is get the `{{.....etc.....}}` stuff that I see on the URL when I load it in Firefox into my script so I can parse a value out of it. I've Googled a ton but I haven't found a good answer as to how to actually get the `{{...}}` stuff from a URL ending in `.json` into an object in a Python script.

Answer (score 431):

Get data from the URL and then call `json.loads` e.g.

**Python3 example**:

```
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google") as url:
    data = json.load(url)
    print(data)
```

**Python2 example**:

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

The output would result in something like this:

```
{
"results" : [
    {
    "address_components" : [
        {
            "long_name" : "Charleston and Huff",
            "short_name" : "Charleston and Huff",
            "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
        },
        {
            "long_name" : "Mountain View",
            "short_name" : "Mountain View",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
...
```

Comment: Rather than use `json.loads` which consumes a string use (which is why `.read()` is required, use `json.load(response)` instead.

Comment: PSL only, concise and efficient

Comment: Is `urllib2` preferable in Python2?

Comment: try `data = json.load(url)` instead of `data = json.loads(url.read().decode())` as @awatts said

Comment: tip: access the `data` keys as `data['myValue']`, see [the below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308120)

Answer (score 160):

I'll take a guess that you actually want to get data from the URL:

```
jsonurl = urlopen(url)
text = json.loads(jsonurl.read()) # <-- read from it
```

Or, check out [JSON decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) in the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('someurl')
print r.json() # if response type was set to JSON, then you'll automatically have a JSON response here...
```

Answer (score 32):

This gets a dictionary in JSON format from a webpage with Python 2.X and Python 3.X:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    # For Python 3.0 and later
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json


def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    """
    Receive the content of ``url``, parse it as JSON and return the object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    url : str

    Returns
    -------
    dict
    """
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)


url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
       "address=googleplex&sensor=false")
print(get_jsonparsed_data(url))
```

See also: [Read and write example for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769)

Answer (score 30):

I have found this to be the easiest and most efficient way to get JSON from a webpage when using Python 3:

```
import json,urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.github.com/users?since=100").read()
output = json.loads(data)
print (output)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You need to import urlopen from urllib.request, i.e.
`from urllib.request import urlopen`

Answer (score 17):

you need `import requests` and use from json() method :

```
source = requests.get("url").json()
print(source)
```

Of course, this method also works:

```
import json,urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen("url").read()
output = json.loads(data)
print (output)
```

`json.loads` will decode it into a Python object using this [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table), for example a JSON object will become a Python `dict`.

Answer (score 9):

All that the call to `urlopen()` does (according to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)) is return a file-like object. Once you have that, you need to call its `read()` method to actually pull the JSON data across the network.

Something like:

```
jsonurl = urlopen(url)

text = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
print text
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, json.load() will work instead of json.loads()

```
import json
import urllib

url = 'https://api.github.com/users?since=100'
output = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
print(output)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work in Python 3. json.load is just a wrapper around json.loads that calls read() for a file-like object. json.loads requires a string object and the output of urllib.urlopen(url).read() is a bytes object.  So one has to get the file encoding in order to make it work in Python 3.

In this example we query the headers for the encoding and fall back to utf-8 if we don't get one. The headers object is different between Python 2 and 3 so it has to be done different ways. Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) would avoid all this, but sometimes you need to stick to the standard library.

```
import json
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen

DEFAULT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
url = 'https://api.github.com/users?since=100'
urlResponse = urlopen(url)

if hasattr(urlResponse.headers, 'get_content_charset'):
    encoding = urlResponse.headers.get_content_charset(DEFAULT_ENCODING)
else:
    encoding = urlResponse.headers.getparam('charset') or DEFAULT_ENCODING

output = json.loads(urlResponse.read().decode(encoding))
print(output)
```

Comment: I know six isn't part of the standard library either, but it's shown here for convenience. Without it, you'd need an if/else or try/except block to determine where to get urlopen().

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why all the earlier answers are using `json.loads`. All you need is:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

f = urlopen("https://www.openml.org/d/40996/json")
j = json.load(f)
```

This works because `urlopen` returns a file-like object, which works with `json.load`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use an extra library to parse the json...

`json.loads()` returns a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

So in your case, just do `text["someValueKey"]`

Comment: Not true, it can return almost any type according to this table: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table

Answer (score 4):

For `python>=3.6` you can use:

```
import dload

j = dload.json(url)
```

---

Install [`dload`](https://pypi.org/project/dload/) with:

```
pip3 install dload
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `json.dumps`:

```
import json

# Hier comes you received data

data = json.dumps(response)

print(data)
```

for loading json and write it on file the following code is useful:

```
data = json.loads(json.dumps(Response, sort_keys=False, indent=4))
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=False, indent=4)
```