# JSON to Python Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a weather API JSON data.
I got from a website then converted python dictionary

```
markit_dict = json.loads(response.content)
markit_dict
```

then I turned a Dataframe

[image]

but as you can see the weather column needs to separate 3 different columns

when I choose each column to turn data frame I can

```
wh = pd.DataFrame(openwet.iloc[1,6])
wh

    description     icon id  main
0   broken clouds   04d 803 Clouds
```

Last time I tried to put in a for loop to make dataframe but I could not

**EDIT:**

```
openwet = pd.DataFrame(markit_dict)
openwet['weather'].values
```

output :

```
array([ [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 803, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'broken clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 803, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'broken clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 804, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'overcast clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 804, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'overcast clouds'}],
```

I need to make a Dataframe the weather column. Also I put my json data might be someone can find different way.

```
url = "http://history.openweathermap.org//storage/debd7a72617dd61b0fc871a2c83fcabf.json"
response = requests.get(url)

response.content
```

Comment: You need to use hierarchical / multi indexing for it. It will work. Kindly refer [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

Comment: Hey @Jeril unfortunately I couldn't manage to use. How can I use have you tried?

Comment: can you share a piece of your data?

Comment: I edited today and I put url you can see all data or I put an example of weather column data which you can check. Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) for create `DataFrame` and column `weather` is first select lists with `str[0]`, then convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then to `DataFrame`. (If need rename column names is possible add [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html)) Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original:

```
import urllib.request, json

url = "http://history.openweathermap.org//storage/debd7a72617dd61b0fc871a2c83fcabf.json"
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/12965254/2901002
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
df = json_normalize(data)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['weather'].str[0].values.tolist()).add_prefix('weather.')
print (df1.head())
  weather.description weather.icon  weather.id weather.main
0       broken clouds          04d         803       Clouds
1       broken clouds          04d         803       Clouds
2     overcast clouds          04d         804       Clouds
3     overcast clouds          04d         804       Clouds
4     overcast clouds          04n         804       Clouds

df = pd.concat([df.drop('weather', 1), df1], axis=1)
```

```
print (df.head(10))
   city_id  clouds.all          dt                         dt_iso  \
0  2193733          76  1447462800  2015-11-14 01:00:00 +0000 UTC   
1  2193733          76  1447470000  2015-11-14 03:00:00 +0000 UTC   
2  2193733          88  1447477200  2015-11-14 05:00:00 +0000 UTC   
3  2193733          88  1447480800  2015-11-14 06:00:00 +0000 UTC   
4  2193733          88  1447488000  2015-11-14 08:00:00 +0000 UTC   
5  2193733          88  1447491600  2015-11-14 09:00:00 +0000 UTC   
6  2193733          36  1447495200  2015-11-14 10:00:00 +0000 UTC   
7  2193733          36  1447498800  2015-11-14 11:00:00 +0000 UTC   
8  2193733          88  1447506000  2015-11-14 13:00:00 +0000 UTC   
9  2193733          88  1447513200  2015-11-14 15:00:00 +0000 UTC   

   main.humidity  main.pressure  main.temp  main.temp_max  main.temp_min  \
0             52           1020     291.15         291.15         291.15   
1             45           1018     291.15         291.15         291.15   
2             48           1017     290.15         290.15         290.15   
3             55           1017     289.15         289.15         289.15   
4             58           1017     287.15         287.15         287.15   
5             62           1017     286.15         286.15         286.15   
6             71           1017     286.15         286.15         286.15   
7             71           1016     286.15         286.15         286.15   
8             76           1015     286.15         286.15         286.15   
9             87           1014     287.15         287.15         287.15   

   rain.3h  wind.deg  wind.speed weather.description weather.icon  weather.id  \
0      NaN       250           6       broken clouds          04d         803   
1      NaN       240           7       broken clouds          04d         803   
2      NaN       270           6     overcast clouds          04d         804   
3      NaN       250           4     overcast clouds          04d         804   
4      NaN       310           2     overcast clouds          04n         804   
5      NaN       310           2     overcast clouds          04n         804   
6      NaN       350           1    scattered clouds          03n         802   
7      NaN        10           2    scattered clouds          03n         802   
8      NaN       350           2     overcast clouds          04n         804   
9      NaN       340           3     overcast clouds          04n         804   

  weather.main  
0       Clouds  
1       Clouds  
2       Clouds  
3       Clouds  
4       Clouds  
5       Clouds  
6       Clouds  
7       Clouds  
8       Clouds  
9       Clouds
```

Comment: Wow, this is super cool! Double thank you for answered both versions of Python

Comment: Glad can help you, nice weekend!

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think your are almost there. :)

```
weatherArray = [ [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 803, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'broken clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 803, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'broken clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 804, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'overcast clouds'}],
       [{u'main': u'Clouds', u'id': 804, u'icon': u'04d', u'description': u'overcast clouds'}] ]

for weather in weatherArray:
  for i in weather:
   print(i['main'])
   print(i['id'])
   print(i['icon'])
   print(i['description'])

  print('\n')
```

Use the above code to loop through the contents of weatherArray and add them in different columns.