# Python 3: Trying to get JSON code from request

Tags: python, json, twitter, request

I am trying to pull the JSON code from a `urllib.request` object focusing on twitter. I am doing this out of curiosity and also because I am trying to determine what to request with `Scrappy` in order to write code that bypasses twitter's infinite scrolling and allows me to pull all the tweets off a user's timeline.

(I know there are some packages that already do this but I want to set it up by myself to learn by doing :) )

I have been using the `urllib` package to get the request data, however, I have been running into a frustrating error when I attempt it:

```
import json
import urllib

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://twitter.com/vonkraush") as url:
    data = url.read().decode()

print(json.loads(data))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-208336effb36>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads(data)

  File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

I've tried expressly passing `'utf-8'` into the decoding and a few other methods, but nothing has so far allowed my to bypass this error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `data` is an HTML document, not a JSON object. You cannot pass it to `json.loads()`.

Comment: Odd, I have seen other people suggest this exact same code block on stack exchange: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script

What should I do instead then?

Comment: If there is any JSON in that page, you have to extract it from the page and then call `json.loads()`.

Comment: Gotcha, how would you recommend extracting it then?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. This URL will always return you an HTML page. To get `user` data from `Twitter` use `Twitter Dev API`.

See here, [Twitter Dev API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) might help you to extract information from Twitter. But for that to you will have to authenticate yourself as a Twitter `user`. Make sure you create a Twitter app first and get your OAuth key. It will be your access to Twitter API.

Twitter API uses token based authentication. The Token that you will receive in response from the API call will be your identity as a `user`.

Comment: Twitter API only lets me pull a little over 3000 tweets, I am toying around with direct web scraping to see if I can pull all of a user's tweets.

Comment: This [Twitter Scraper](https://github.com/bpb27/twitter_scraping), might solve your problem.

Comment: I am mostly doing this so I get a better handle on how web scraping with scrapy works, to learn by doing rather than a need to pull a bunch of tweets. They also use selenium rather than scrapy.

Comment: They are using selenium to get the tweet by automating your browser to get data from twitter using a CSS selector i.e. `li.js-stream-item`. It will only get tweets between two dates.

Comment: If you are attempting to scrape the Twitter website you are violating Twitter's terms of service and developer agreement. Your IP address may be blocked by Twitter.