# python: read json with pandas

Tags: python, json

I want to get the timestamp,high,low,open, close for the the json link below but I get only error
 c`harterror                                                Noneresult  [{u'indicators': {u'quote': [{u'high': [45.25,...`

My code is below:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/CPN.BK?range=2y&interval=1d&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true')
output = df[['timestamp','open','high,'low','close']]
```

Please guide how to get the data into dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `pandas` to `read_json` from your url, it will save all json data into one cell (column `chart`, row `result`).

Based on your code, you have to extract the dictionary data for `'timestamp','open','high,'low'` and `'close'`, after that you can pass them to `pandas DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/chart/CPN.BK?range=2y&interval=1d&indicators=quote&includeTimestamps=true')
data = df['chart']['result'][0]
result = {'timestamp':data['timestamp'],
          'open':data['indicators']['quote'][0]['open'],
          'high':data['indicators']['quote'][0]['high'],
          'low':data['indicators']['quote'][0]['low'],
          'close':data['indicators']['quote'][0]['close']
         }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns==['timestamp','open','high','low','close'])
df1
```

`df1` will be:

```
    timestamp    open   high    low     close   
0   1442977200   44.50  45.25   44.25   45.00       
1   1443063600   44.75  45.75   44.50   45.00   
2   1443150000   44.75  45.00   44.25   44.50   
3   1443409200   44.25  44.25   43.00   43.00   
4   1443495600   42.50  44.50   42.25   44.00   
5   1443582000   44.25  44.75   43.50   44.75   
6   1443668400   44.50  45.00   44.25   45.00   
7   1443754800   45.00  45.00   44.00   44.25   
8   1444014000   44.25  44.75   43.75   44.50   
...
```

Alternatively, you can load the json from the url (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)), then extract the dictionary data (`'timestamp','open','high,'low' and 'close'`), pass it to pandas to generate the result dataframe.

Comment: Thanks. How to sort the dataframe started from left with timestamp, follow by open,high,low and close. Now it started, with close,follow by high,low,open and timstamp. Need a correct order.

Comment: @lotteryman, add columns in pd.DataFrame, check updated answer: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns==['timestamp','open','high','low','close'])`