# Getting a json string off a website with python

Tags: python, json, string, web

There is a link with a json string which I can't seem to extract inside a python dictionary.

I tried with the requests library and with beautifullsoup
the link with the website is https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/history/AAPL%3AUS/PX_LAST?timeframe=1_MONTH&period=daily&volumePeriod=daily

For example:

```py
link = "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets2/api/history/AAPL%3AUS/PX_LAST?timeframe=1_MONTH&period=daily&volumePeriod=daily"
import requests
res = requests.get(link)
res.content
```

only gets me a long html text with anything but the text on that website.

How do I scrape of this specific websites string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JSON from webpage into Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)

Comment: `res = requests.get(link).json()`

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, im getting an error. i was trying that before too, also i tried it with the loads example.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the output of `resp.url` .

[image]

You are trying to progmatically access content from a website that is protected against those behaviors.

1. an access key can help you.
2. you can trick the detection in various ways which could be semi legal .. but requests probably cannot get you there.