# Scraping wsj.com

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape some data from wsj.com and print it. The actual website is: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?mod=md_home_overview_stk_main and the data is NYSE Issues Advancing, Declining and NYSE Share Volume Advancing, Declining.

I tried using beautifulsoup after watching a youtube video but I can't get any of the classes to return a value inside body.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get('https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?mod=md_home_overview_stk_main').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

body = soup.find('body')

adv = body.find('td', class_='WSJTables--table__cell--2dzGiO7q WSJTheme--table__cell--1At-VGNg ')


print(adv)
```

Also while inspecting elements in Network I noticed that this data is also available as a JSON.

Here is the link: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?id=%7B%22application%22%3A%22WSJ%22%2C%22marketsDiaryType%22%3A%22overview%22%7D&type=mdc_marketsdiary

So I wrote another script to try and parse this data using JSON but again its not working.

Here is the code:

```
import json

import requests

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?id=%7B%22application%22%3A%22WSJ%22%2C%22marketsDiaryType%22%3A%22overview%22%7D&type=mdc_marketsdiary'

response = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

print(response)
```

The error I get is:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

I also tried a few different methods from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script) and none seem to work.

Can you please set me on the right path how to scrape this data?

Comment: what's your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


params = {
    'id': '{"application":"WSJ","marketsDiaryType":"overview"}',
    'type': 'mdc_marketsdiary'
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"
}
r = requests.get(
    "https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks", params=params, headers=headers).json()


data = json.dumps(r, indent=4)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{
    "id": "{\"application\":\"WSJ\",\"marketsDiaryType\":\"overview\"}",
    "type": "mdc_marketsdiary",
    "data": {
        "instrumentSets": [
            {
                "headerFields": [
                    {
                        "value": "name",
                        "label": "Issues"
                    }
                ],
                "instruments": [
                    {
                        "name": "Advancing",
                        "NASDAQ": "169",
                        "NYSE": "69"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Declining",
                        "NASDAQ": "3,190",
                        "NYSE": "2,973"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Unchanged",
                        "NASDAQ": "24",
                        "NYSE": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Total",
                        "NASDAQ": "3,383",
                        "NYSE": "3,052"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "headerFields": [
                    {
                        "value": "name",
                        "label": "Issues At"
                    }
                ],
                "instruments": [
                    {
                        "name": "New Highs",
                        "NASDAQ": "53",
                        "NYSE": "14"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "New Lows",
                        "NASDAQ": "1,406",
                        "NYSE": "1,620"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "headerFields": [
                    {
                        "value": "name",
                        "label": "Share Volume"
                    }
                ],
                "instruments": [
                    {
                        "name": "Total",
                        "NASDAQ": "4,454,691,895",
                        "NYSE": "7,790,947,818"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Advancing",
                        "NASDAQ": "506,192,012",
                        "NYSE": "219,412,232"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Declining",
                        "NASDAQ": "3,948,035,191",
                        "NYSE": "7,570,377,893"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Unchanged",
                        "NASDAQ": "464,692",
                        "NYSE": "1,157,693"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "4:00 PM EDT 3/09/20"
    },
    "hash": "{\"id\":\"{\\\"application\\\":\\\"WSJ\\\",\\\"marketsDiaryType\\\":\\\"overview\\\"}\",\"type\":\"mdc_marketsdiary\",\"data\":{\"instrumentSets\":[{\"headerFields\":[{\"value\":\"name\",\"label\":\"Issues\"}],\"instruments\":[{\"name\":\"Advancing\",\"NASDAQ\":\"169\",\"NYSE\":\"69\"},{\"name\":\"Declining\",\"NASDAQ\":\"3,190\",\"NYSE\":\"2,973\"},{\"name\":\"Unchanged\",\"NASDAQ\":\"24\",\"NYSE\":\"10\"},{\"name\":\"Total\",\"NASDAQ\":\"3,383\",\"NYSE\":\"3,052\"}]},{\"headerFields\":[{\"value\":\"name\",\"label\":\"Issues At\"}],\"instruments\":[{\"name\":\"New Highs\",\"NASDAQ\":\"53\",\"NYSE\":\"14\"},{\"name\":\"New Lows\",\"NASDAQ\":\"1,406\",\"NYSE\":\"1,620\"}]},{\"headerFields\":[{\"value\":\"name\",\"label\":\"Share Volume\"}],\"instruments\":[{\"name\":\"Total\",\"NASDAQ\":\"4,454,691,895\",\"NYSE\":\"7,790,947,818\"},{\"name\":\"Advancing\",\"NASDAQ\":\"506,192,012\",\"NYSE\":\"219,412,232\"},{\"name\":\"Declining\",\"NASDAQ\":\"3,948,035,191\",\"NYSE\":\"7,570,377,893\"},{\"name\":\"Unchanged\",\"NASDAQ\":\"464,692\",\"NYSE\":\"1,157,693\"}]}],\"timestamp\":\"4:00 PM EDT 3/09/20\"}}"
}
```

> Note: You can access it as `dict` `print(r.keys())`.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution. Thank you. 

Can you please explain params and headers you added and where did you find them and in which cases are they needed?

Comment: You welcome :) glad to help. Currently am online through phone . I’ll explain that once I get back on laptop

Comment: you welcome, check [headers](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) and [parameters](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: very helpful tutorial. Do you always need header and where did you find the header?

Comment: @trustory sometimes you need headers and sometimes not. that's an open question which you can answer yourself about it during working with code. and you can find the headers within your browser developer-tools and check the network section and then you can locate which headers used.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many noob questions. I just started learning programming so all these terms and the language are all brand new to me.

Thank you for your assistance while I learn and grow my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a header on the url so that it will not return error=404.

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen   
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/stocks?id=%7B%22application%22%3A%22WSJ%22%2C%22marketsDiaryType%22%3A%22overview%22%7D&type=mdc_marketsdiary'
# put a header on the request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
with urlopen(req) as response:
    page_html = response.read()
df = pd.DataFrame()    
data = json.loads(page_html).get('data')
for instrumentSets in data.get('instrumentSets'):
    for k,v in instrumentSets.items():
        if k == 'instruments':
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(v))
df=df.rename(columns = {'name':'Issues'})
df

Result:
```

[image]