# Can't seem to access Metatags

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, newspaper3k

I need to scrape the author and date from a news article, but I'm having trouble accessing some information in the meta tags.

```
import requests, random, re, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.parse
import time
from newspaper import Article


url = ['https://www.wsj.com/articles/covid-19-is-dividing-the-american-worker-11598068859?mod=hp_lead_pos7',

##WALL STREET JOURNAL
for link in url:

    #Try 1
    #Get the published date -- this is where I have problems. 
    webpage = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs(webpage.text, "html.parser")
    date = soup.find("meta", {"name": "article.published"})
    print(date)



    #Try 2
    #Access date from the <time> tag instead
    for tag in soup.find_all('time', {"class": "timestamp article__timestamp flexbox__flex--1"}):
        date = tag.text
        print(date)





    #Get the author name -- this part works
    article = Article(link, language='en')
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    # print(article.html)

    author = article.authors
    date = article.publish_date
    author = author[0]

    day_month = str("Check Date")
    print(day_month + "," + "," + "," + str(author))
```

When I print out soup, I can get the Meta tags in the output, so I know they're there, but i can't seem to access them with either method.

Here's the output I'm getting so far:
None
Check Date,,,Christopher Mims

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping wsj.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606633/scraping-wsj-com)

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Also did you look at my [overview document on newspaper](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview)?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex, Yes, and I just marked it as so. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a User Agent the website returns a different page (404 page not found). You can specify any valid use agent e.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
}
url = ['https://www.wsj.com/articles/covid-19-is-dividing-the-american-worker-11598068859?mod=hp_lead_pos7']

## WALL STREET JOURNAL
for link in url:

    # Get the published date -- this is where I have problems.
    webpage = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = bs(webpage.text, "html.parser")
    date = soup.find("meta", {"name": "article.published"})
    print(date['content'])

    # Access date from the <time> tag instead
    for tag in soup.find_all('time', {"class": "timestamp article__timestamp flexbox__flex--1"}):
        date = tag.text
        print(date.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
2020-08-22T04:01:00.000Z
Aug. 22, 2020 12:01 am ET
```

Answer (score 0):

*Newspaper* has some issues with query efficiency, because it has some slight navigational problems with locating certain data elements in your target HTML. I have noted that you need to review the target's HTML to determine what items can be queried with the functions/methods within *Newspaper*

The *meta-tags* on the Wall Street Journal contain the author's name, article title, article summary, article published data and article keywords can be extracted without using BeautifulSoup.

```
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Config

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'

config = Config()
config.browser_user_agent = user_agent

url = 'https://www.wsj.com/articles/covid-19-is-dividing-the-american-worker-11598068859?mod=hp_lead_pos7'
article = Article(url, config=config)
article.download()
article.parse()
article_meta_data = article.meta_data

article_published_date = str({value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'article.published'})
print(article_published_date)

article_author = sorted({value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items()if key == 'author'})
print(article_author)

article_title = {value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'article.headline'}
print(article_title)

article_summary = {value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'article.summary'}
print(article_summary)

keywords = ''.join({value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'news_keywords'})
article_keywords = sorted(keywords.lower().split(','))
print(article_keywords)
```

I hope that this answer helps you in someway.

P.S. *BeautifulSoup* is a dependency in *Newspaper*, so it can be called this way:

```
from newspaper.utils import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Wow! Great way to approach the problem. Thanks for your help. This will speed up some  work I do quite a bit.

Comment: @SethMcCombie You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem please accept it as the solution to your question.

Comment: @SethMcCombie Since you use newspaper, you might find my usage document beneficial -- https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview