# Elements on page don't exist when scraping wsj.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Python to scrape a webpage. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set local variables 
URL = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/bonds'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Get Master data table and Last update from URL
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "WSJTables--table--1QzSOCfq "})

print(table)
```

The result of that code is nothing--I can't find the table and not sure why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yeap my bad the correct name is 'WSJTables--table--1QzSOCfq' I just edited the question

Comment: The tables are dynamic. They don't exist in the initial page. They are loaded/constructed via javascript.

Comment: It's actually static but you need request headers or WSJ gives a 404. See [scraping wsj.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606633/scraping-wsj-com). After adding the header it worked for me with `print(soup.select(".WSJTables--table--1QzSOCfq"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `user-agent` header, otherwise the page thinks that you’re a bot and will block you. Also note you had an extra space in your class name

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/bonds'


HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "WSJTables--table--1QzSOCfq"})
print(table)
```