# BeautifulSoup find_all() returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script to retrieve a street address from a website. Below is one of the steps in my script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

name = '1QB Information technologies HQ'
province = 'BC'

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/' + name + '/' + province

html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
address = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'jsMapBubbleAddress'})

print(address)
```

However, the code above returns:

```
[]
```

while I am expecting:

```
7-3318 Oak St
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Weird, this works on my machine. Can you try printing `html_text` to see whether it returns a long string of html text?

Comment: This does print an output for me. Try adding the `user-agent` header. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885124/elements-on-page-dont-exist-when-scraping-wsj-com/64885812#64885812).

Answer (score 0):

Here this code is working fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

name = '1QB Information technologies HQ'
province = 'BC'

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/' + name + '/' + province
url = url
print(url)
print('https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/1QB+Information+technologies+HQ/British+Columbia+BC')
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
address = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'jsMapBubbleAddress'})
#To get to all data 
print([d.text for d in address])
# only for 7-3318 Oak St
print([d.text for d in address if d.text == '7-3318 Oak St'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Code works for me as well. But perhaps you can try adding the user-agent in the headers parameter:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

name = '1QB Information technologies HQ'
province = 'BC'

url = 'https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/' + name + '/' + province
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
address = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'jsMapBubbleAddress'})

print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems with site parsing may arise because when you try to request a site, it may consider that this is a bot, so that this does not happen, you need to send `headers` that contain [`user-agent` in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), then the site will assume that you're a user and display information.

This is the most basic technique to avoid being blocked which leads to different HTML with some sort of an error, and that's why there no such selector that you were looking for.

Also, if you want to collect data from all pages, you need to use pagination. More about pagination you can find out in the [Pagination Techniques to Scrape Data from any Website in Python](https://dimitryzub.medium.com/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#5a11) blog post.

In our case, we can use a `while` loop to iterate through all the pages. Since the while cycle is infinite, you need to set a stop condition, for this you can take into account the presence of a button on the page to go to the next page `(".pageCount+ .pageButton")`, the absence of which will serve as a condition for stopping the cycle:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pageCount+ .pageButton"):
    page_num += 1    # if button is present we paginate to the next page
else:
    break
```

Check code and how pagination working [in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-yellowpages-adress-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

data = []

page_num = 1

while True:
    html = requests.get(f"https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/{page_num}/1QB+Information+technologies+HQ/British+Columbia+BC", headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    print(f"Extracting page: {page_num}")

    print("-" * 10)
  
    for adresses in soup.select(".listing_right_top_section"):
        name = adresses.select_one(".jsListingName").text
        try:
            address = adresses.select_one(".listing__address--full").text.strip()
        except:
            address = None
            
        data.append({
            "name": name,
            "address": address
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pageCount+ .pageButton"):
        page_num += 1
    else:
        break  
      
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "name": "WireDen",
    "address": "303-1095 McKenzie Ave, Victoria, BC V8P 2L5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Swift Kick Computers",
    "address": "3951 Blenkinsop Rd,, BC V8P 3P8"
  },
  {
    "name": "Zycomp Systems Ltd",
    "address": "209-1497 Admirals Rd, Victoria, BC V9A 2P8"
  },
  {
    "name": "Janor Solutions Inc",
    "address": "1005 Ridgeway Pl, Victoria, BC V8X 3C5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Orca Consulting Group",
    "address": "4068 Haro Rd, Victoria, BC V8N 4B4"
  },
  # ...
]
```