# Load a JSON File from a URL request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Currently, I am using the code below to load a JSON file. However, I want to load the JSON data without saving a file to my laptop. I tried directly to load however it is giving me an error.

First Code:

```
url = "example.url"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
with open('save.json', 'wb') as outf:
    outf.write(response.content)
file = open("save.json")
data = json.load(file)
```

Code Tried:

```
url = "example.url"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = json.load(response.content)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JSON from webpage into Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url = "example.url"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that directly from your
`response` object.

```
response.json()
```

Note that it will **raise** an error if the content of the response is not in a valid json format.