# JSON from webpage into Python script: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, json, python-requests, kivy, urllib

I made a program and it works with a local json (data) file!

Code Block:

```
def datas(self):        
        
        with open ("C:\\Users\\Messi\\Desktop\\Python\\\\tek.json", "r") as dosya:            
            dataApi = json.load(dosya)     
        return dataApi
```

I uploaded this data json to a website which is a Lemp Server!
https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json

I changed the code block to the:

```
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json") as url:
    dataApi= json.load(url)
return dataApi
```

There is an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 150, in <module>
     BetpredictorApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 923, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 696, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 403, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 16, in __init__
     self.data = self.datas()
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 134, in datas
     with urllib.request.urlopen("https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json") as url:
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
     response = meth(req, response)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
     response = self.parent.error(
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
     return self._call_chain(*args)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
     result = func(*args)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Also:
https://www.pythonpool.com/urllib-error-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/

```
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen     
url = "https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json"
request_site = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
webpage = urlopen(request_site).read()
print(webpage[:500])
```

In above solution i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 151, in <module>
     BetpredictorApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 923, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 696, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\kivyEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 403, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 16, in __init__
     self.Today = self.todayMatches()
   File "c:\Users\Messi\Desktop\Python\Projects\Football Tips\Kivy\main.py", line 124, in todayMatches
     for i in range(len(self.data['today']["home"])):
 TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How possible is it that this json is works perfect locally! Team names are STR and stats are also integer! But with above method that i get error

I tried some other methods in but not tried all!
[How to get JSON from webpage into Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)

Could you please help me to fix this :)
I have 500 hours on Python that i like it but stucked here

Thanks

Comment: If I use the requests library on your first code and get `https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json` it works fine for me. What are you trying to do in the second example? `https://www.gamefaqs.com` returns html, not json.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a CORS issue? Try something like https://github.com/bulletmark/corsproxy.

Comment: import requests and source = requests.get("https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json").json() worked for me app is now working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what the problem is, but if I use this code it works fine from my system:

```
import requests
url = "https://bestpurpleshampoo.com/tek.json"
response = requests.get(url).json()
print(response['today']['home'])
```

Result:

```
['Ajax', 'Liverpool', 'Club Brugge', 'FC Porto'... truncated ...]
```

If you need to install requests library, use: `pip install requests`