# How to get json?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

[In browser I got this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUnef.png) I'm trying to get json but got error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/idxv2/getBidsByMintAddresses?hideExpired=true&mintAddresses=GXXBt4tzJ6aGoNvz87Xzh1PqXwB4qVRdQdHcX65iXtRZ&direction=1&field=2&limit=500&offset=0'
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Your response is empty. Why are you trying to load it as JSON?

Comment: You forgot to check the HTTP status code which is 403

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JSON from webpage into Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965203/how-to-get-json-from-webpage-into-python-script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse/read and use JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json-in-python)

Comment: The response says access denied, you aren't getting the data. Try passing a user agent. Good luck.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Try printing `response.content`.

Comment: I dont need content.Thanks for help.I want to get json the same as in the screenshot in my theme

Comment: `.content` or `.text` are the raw response from the server, which your error says they are empty, or **not JSON**. Requests does not send the same HTTP headers as your browser

Comment: great thanks for your answer,i am misunderstood how it working

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference would be:

```
import requests

URL = 'whatever'

with requests.get(URL) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json()
```

*raise_for_status()* will raise requests.exceptions.HTTPError if the status code indicates some kind of error. Clearly, you might want to wrap that in try/except

Answer (score -2):

Use builtin json function of the response

Also best practice to check status codes

```
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
  data = response.json()
  print(data)
else:
  print("unexpected response")
```

Answer (score -2):

Note this:

```
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Response has a built-in method for this purpose. It's called as the `json()`

```
data = resp.Json()
```

Additionally, I would preface this with a conditional `if` check:

```
if resp.Ok:
    ...
else:
    print('NOK!')
    r.raise_for_status()
```