# Can't change value into json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am writing simple application which has json file for store some user's information.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "last result": 15,
            "login": "admin",
            "id": 1,
            "password": "1"
        },
        {
            "last result": 2,
            "login": "user",
            "id": 2,
            "password": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

For example I need to change value "last result" from "user" = admin
I have method for take data from json:

```
def load_data_from_json(test_file_name):
    with open(test_file_name, encoding="utf-8") as data_file:
        return json.load(data_file)
```

test_file_name - json's name (in my code it's - "auth.json")

Then I'm trying to set new value:

```
def set_last_result(login, new_result):
    for user in load_data_from_json("auth.json")["users"]:
        if user["login"] == login:
            user["last result"] = new_result
    raise Exception("User '{}' not found.".format(login))
```

But I have an error:

```
  File "/Users/future/PycharmProjects/module_for_test/user.py", line 53, in set_last_result
    raise Exception("User '{}' not found.".format(login))
Exception: User 'admin' not found.
```

If I just take the "last result"value

```
def get_last_result(login):
    for user in load_data_from_json("auth.json")["users"]:
        if user["login"] == login:
            return user["last result"]
    raise Exception("User '{}' not found.".format(login))
```

All work's well. Where is my mistake?

P.S. I'm using Python 3.4

P.S.S Fix my error message.

Comment: I don't see any `print(user["admin"])` in your code, and more important I don't see any `"admin"` key in your user dictionary, that's where the `KeyError` probably comes from.

Comment: Users don't have 'admin' keys, they have 'login' keys.  When you print `user['admin']` you generate a key error.

Comment: Sorry, I posted not correct error message, now i've fixed it.

Comment: Your get method returns when it finds the user. The set method does not, thus it will always finish the for loop and then raise the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write JSON data to file in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/write-json-data-to-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your concern about the exception:**

as @Dunes said, if you don't want to raise the exception, you cannot allow the for loop to finish, so in your case you can return:

```
def set_last_result(login, new_result):
    for user in load_data_from_json("auth.json")["users"]:
        if user["login"] == login:
            user["last result"] = new_result
            return
    raise Exception("User '{}' not found.".format(login))
```

in a more general situation, not just inside a function, you can use `for ... else`:

```
def set_last_result(login, new_result):
    for user in load_data_from_json("auth.json")["users"]:
        if user["login"] == login:
            user["last result"] = new_result
            break
    else:  # will execute only if `for` loops through all values without break
        raise Exception("User '{}' not found.".format(login))
```

---

**But there is also a different problem:**

You are updating a local variable `user` which will have no effect whatsoever in the outer scope of the `set_last_result` function, most notably it won't update the loaded json file.

To do that you need to [Write JSON data to file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12309269/1176601).