# Write JSON field with its key

Tags: python, json, file, field

I have the JSON variable `var` with the following content:

```
[{"name":"name0", "surname":"surname01", "surname2":"surname02", "number": 0}, {"name":"name1", "surname":"surname11", "surname2":"surname12", "number": 1}]
```

And I want to write in a JSON file just the `name` and the `number` fields.
Currently, I am doing it the following way:

```
f.write('[')
for a, i in enumerate(var):
  f.write('{"name":' + i['name'] + ', "number":' + i['number'] + '}')
  if(a==0):
    f.write(',')
f.write(']')
f.close()
```

Is there a better way to write to a file a subset of the JSON fields in Python?

Comment: Three changes. 1) Use json library. 2) Use with statement. 3) Consider whether you need to wrap it in an array. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12309296/1175496) describes the `json` library.

Comment: I would make a python list/dictionary and `json.dump` that instead of manually writing text to a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) module to make this shorter;

```
import json
json.dump([{'name': i['name'], 'number': i['number']} for i in var ], f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `json` module and convert it to al list

```
import json
newVar = []
for i in var:
    newVar.append({'name': i['name'], 'number': i['number']})
return json.dumps(newVar)
```

however this is not much better, just different

Comment: You can use `json.dump(newVar, f)` to write the result to a file.