# How to write content back to a json file using python?

Tags: python, json, google-maps

I have a json file which looks like https://www.dropbox.com/s/raplkyl5le1rmh9/testDehil.json?dl=0

My task was to read the address and find the **full specific geo-code** and update back the json file. I am able to do the following till now:

--> Read the jsonfile and pass the address to Google API to get the exact latitute and longitude.

I am stuck at this point where i need to update the read file to the newly received exact latitude and longitude.

My code is :

```
import json
import requests
import time
import shutil
import os
from pprint import pprint

def open_json():
  with open('/home/nishant/Documents/Python/Gnitin/testDehil.json') as json_data:
     d = json.load(json_data)
     #json_data.close()
     #pprint(d) 
     for item in d: 
       a = item['address']['address']
       google_call(a)
       time.sleep(10)
     # EXTRACT THE address from each and pass it below: ## 



def google_call(add):
   address = add  #This needs to be run in loop
   api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   api_response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}'.format(address, api_key))
   api_response_dict = api_response.json()

   if api_response_dict['status'] == 'OK':
      latitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
      longitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
      print 'Latitude:', latitude
      print 'Longitude:', longitude
      write_back_cool_stuff(latitude,longitude)

def write_back_cool_stuff(lat,lon):
   ## How to write back to the json file with received lat and long ? 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   source = "/home/nishant/Documents/Python/Gnitin/testDehil.json"
   dest = "/home/nishant/Documents/Python/Gnitin/testDehil_clean.json" 
   shutil.copyfile(source,dest)
   open_json()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the source JSON to a dictionary, then get the coordinates for each item (if possible) and add these coordinates (or unknown value (`None`)) as address properties. Save the updated data as JSON.

```
import os
import json
import time
import shutil
import requests


def add_coordinates(source, dest):
    with open(source, 'r') as file_object:
        json_data = json.load(file_object)

    for item in json_data:
        address = item['address']['address']
        latitude, longitude = google_call(address)

        # add latitude and longitude as address properties
        item['address']['latitude'] = latitude
        item['address']['longitude'] = longitude

        # save updated json_data
        with open(dest, 'w') as file_object:
            json.dump(json_data, file_object)

        time.sleep(10)


def google_call(address):
    api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    api_response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&key={1}'.format(address, api_key))
    api_response_dict = api_response.json()

    latitude = None
    longitude = None

    if api_response_dict['status'] == 'OK':
        latitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        longitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']

        print 'Latitude:', latitude
        print 'Longitude:', longitude

    return latitude, longitude


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = "/home/nishant/Documents/Python/Gnitin/testDehil.json"
    dest = "/home/nishant/Documents/Python/Gnitin/testDehil_clean.json"
    shutil.copyfile(source, dest)
    add_coordinates(source, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

json encoded data consists of key-value pairs.  The same structure can also be represented as a dictionary in python.  If you have a dictionary, and want to serialize and store it to a file, you would use the [`dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) function from the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

Consider the following example, implementing your `write_back_cool_stuff` function:

```
import json

def write_back_cool_stuff(lat, lon):
    # create a dictionary containing your key-value pairs
    data = {'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
    # get a file handle for writing
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        # dump json encoded data to the file
        json.dump(data, f)
```

it would be used like this:

```
write_back_cool_stuff(30.0, 50.0)
```

and the content of the file will contain:

```
{"lat": 30.0, "lon": 50.0}
```