# How to save python dictionary into json files?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary, for example:

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

And I want it to be saved in a json file.

How can I do this with the original python json library?

Please note that I am running Python 3.5.2, which has a build-in json library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 24):

You can also dump json file directly using `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps`.

```
import json
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
with open("your_json_file", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(a , fp)
```

`json.dumps` is mainly used to display dictionaries as a json format with the type of string. While dump is used for saving to file. Using this to save to file is obsolete.

The previous example only save the file to json but does not make it very pretty. So instead you could do this:

```
json.dump(a, fp, indent = 4) # you can also do sort_keys=True as well
# this work the same for json.dumps
```

This makes the json file more user friendly to read. [the pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)  has some good description on how to use the json module.

To retrieve your data back, you can use the `load` function.

```
a = json.load(fp) # load back the original dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it was particularly helpful to give the indent tip, it really improves readability.

Answer (score 4):

#### This may help you...

```
import json
a = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 24}
js = json.dumps(a)

# Open new json file if not exist it will create
fp = open('test.json', 'a')

# write to json file
fp.write(js)

# close the connection
fp.close()
```

Comment: should use the with syntax:  with open('test.json', 'a') as f:

Comment: the 6th line: `fp = open('test.json', 'a')` there is a 'a', what's it doing here?

Comment: 'a' for appending with exiting file. You may read https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation

Answer (score 1):

show you code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8
'''黄哥Python'''

import json

a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}


with open("json.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

check this-

import json

```
a = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
json_str = json.dumps(a)
```

with `open('data.json', 'w')` as `f:json.dump(data, f)`

Answer (score 1):

Most of other answers are correct but this will also print data in prettify and sorted manner.

```
import json
a = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 24}
js = json.dumps(a, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
with open('test.json', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(js)
```