# Python dataframe to JSON add additional fields

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am looking to transform my dataframe to json

```
Age   Eye     Gender
30    blue    male
```

My current code, I convert the dataframe to json and get the below result:

```
json_file = df.to_json(orient='records')

json_file

[{'age':'30'},{'eye':'blue'},{'gender':'male'}]
```

However, I want to add an **additional layer** that would state the id and name to the json data and then label it as 'info'.

```
{'id':'5231'
 'name':'Bob'
 'info': [
          {'age':'30'},{'eye':'blue'},{'gender':'male'}
         ]
 }
```

How would I add the additional fields? I tried reading the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) however I do not see a clear answer on how to add the additional fields in during dataframe to json conversion.

Comment: Where is that additional information coming from? What format is it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you provided this is your answer:

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'id':'5231',
    'name':'Bob',
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[30], 'Eye':['blue'], 'Gender': ['male']})
json = df.to_json(orient='records')

a['info'] = json
```

Comment: hi, how do you output the result as a json file?

Comment: @Hachi you can use this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file