# How do i print a json output into a specific file path?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, converters

Im having troubles saving the output into a specific file path like a csv file output just that my codes are simpler and it have 'with open(xxx)'.

So here are my codes. How do i print 'out' into a specific file path e.g /home/pi/Desktop/sample.json?

```
    import csv
    import json

    with open(csvfile, "a") as output:
       fieldnames = ['Name', 'Number', 'ID', 'Address']
       writer = csv.writer(output,delimiter = ',', lineterminator="\n")
       writer.writerows([fieldnames])
```

Comment: Check this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309296/4851248

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: @RamLakhan hi! thanks for replying!! I've tried it but i realised that data = (hardcoded content)  but i am using a variable.

Comment: @Darkstarone hi!! thanks for the reply :) yes ive tried that too, its similar to the one in the website Ram gave

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to leave you Python code as it is and use the power of the shell!

Assuming the script is in you current working directory, try this:

```
python myscript.py > sample.json
```

This will redirect the output (stdout) of your script to a file automatically creating it.