# Python Export JSON collections from multiple folders into separate tab-delimited files

Tags: python, json

I have 500 folders each containing varying numbers (ranging between 20-40) of JSON collections. I'm able to extract the contents of each folder manually and individually in Python by following answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
import os, json
path_to_json = 'C:/Users/SomeFolder'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
#list all the files in the folder
print (json_files)

for js in json_files:
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
#can only print to screen all the json files - need help saving to a tab-delimited file 
       print (json.load(json_file))
```

However, it would be quite laborious and obviously very tiresome considering this is must done 500 times. A faster automated approach for repetitively extracting the contents of each JSON folder into tab-delimited files would be most welcome. Thanks

Comment: Use the `glob` module and find the right expression to match all your files, for example `*/*.json`.

Comment: Use `os.walk()` to walk through your folders recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, json


current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

all_directories = [x[0] for x in os.walk(current_directory)]

for directory in all_directories:
    path_to_json = directory
    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
    #list all the files in the folder
    print (json_files)

    for js in json_files:
        with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js)) as json_file:
    #can only print to screen all the json files - need help saving to a tab-delimited file 
           print (json.load(json_file))
```

This will find all folders where you execute this script. Then it will iterate folders and do the job. You need to copy this to where you store folders.

Comment: I tried editing your code to save the output to a tab-delimited file. see above