# In python, how do you write a text file that contains brakets and quotes?

Tags: python, variables, text

Python beginner here, I am really struggling with a text file I want to print:

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": 
[127.03790738341824,-21.727244054924235]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}}
```

The fact that has multiple brackets confused me and it throws `Syntax Error` after trying this:

```
def test():
    f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
    lat_test = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lat
    lon_test = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon
    f.write("{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [%s, %s]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}}" % (str(lat_test), str(lat_test)))
    f.close()
```

As you can see, I have my own variable for latitude and longitude, but python is  throwing a syntax error:

```
File "hello.py", line 90
f.write("{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [%s, %s]}, "type": 
"Feature"" % (str(lat_test), str(lat_test)))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your text file in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309296/5538805

Comment: the actual format of the file will be geojson. I figured I will just change the extension from txt to js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you're passing to `f.write()` isn't formatted correctly.  Try:

```
f.write('{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [%s, %s]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}}' % (lat_test, lon_test))
```

This uses the single quote as the outermost set of quotes and allows embedding of double quotes.  Also, you don't need the `str()` around the lat and long as `%s` will run `str()` on it for you.  You're second one was incorrect too (you passed lat_test twice), and I fixed it in the example above.

If what you're doing here is writing JSON, it could be useful to use Python's JSON module to help convert a Python dictionary into a JSON one:

```
import json

lat_test = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lat
lon_test = vehicle.location.global_relative_frame.lon

d = {
    'Geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': [lat_test, lon_test],
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {},
    },
}

with open('helloworld.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a tripple quote:

```
f.write("""{"geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [%s, %s]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}}""" % (str(lat_test), str(lat_test)))
```

But in this specific case json package does the job.