# python from list of tuple create json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, zabbix

I ask advice. I need to create a JSON object with the same keys. This is necessary to send a request to zabbix for host.create .
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/ru/manual/api/reference/host/create 
If you specify more than one group, it accepts only

```
{"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}
```

Does not understand:

```
{"groupid": ["2","8"]}
```

I suppose to use a structure.

```
[("groupid","2"),("groupid","8")]
```

I solved the problem in this way, but I do not understand how to convert to JSON, because the keys are not strings

```
import json
from json import JSONEncoder


class SameKeys(JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.name)


data = [("groupid", "2"), ("groupid", "8")]

a = {SameKeys("groupid"): "2", SameKeys("groupid"): "8"}
print(a)
```

But I can not understand how to do it better so as not to make crutches, there may already be a ready solution, but having spent time I did not find anything suitable. Thank you for any advice

Comment: `{"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}` is not a valid python `dict`

Comment: that's not possible. same keys = not a dict

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan it's valid, but it only keeps the last item

Comment: you can try for list of two dicts .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Comment: `'{"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}'`? JSON is just text.

Comment: I understand that this is not a valid JSON. I need just such a kind that I would send a request to Zabbigx. Everything I've come to do

class SameKeys(JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.name)

data = [("groupid","2"),("groupid","8")]

a={SameKeys("groupid"):"2", SameKeys("groupid"):"8"}


but how to convert all this into JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is it valid JSON?

Yes, `{"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}` is valid JSON and I do not understand what made you [think otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539701/python-from-list-of-tuple-create-json#comment84075377_48539701). RFC8259 [says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4)

> the names within an object
> [SHOULD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#section-3) be unique

because if they are not then

> the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable

But it is not mandatory.

## Do you need it?

I read the [docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/host/create) you linked and I did not find anything suggesting that you need an object with several members named "groupid". In the example there is an object with a member "groups" whose value is an array:

```
{
    ...
    "params": {
        ...
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "50"
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

As I see it, in order to add the host to several groups you are expected to include all the groups in the array.

```
{
    ...
    "params": {
        ...
        "groups": [
            {
                "groupid": "2"
            },
            {
                "groupid": "8"
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately I did not have a chance to test it.

## How to do it

Whatever, it looks like you want to convert a list of items like

```
data = [("groupid","2"),("groupid","8")]
```

into a JSON object with the corresponding members. Well a JSON object is just text, all you have to do is build the string as you iterate over the items.

```
obj = '{' + ', '.join('"{}": "{}"'.format(k, v) for k, v in data) + '}'
print(obj)
```

will print

```
{"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}
```

Comment: Good afternoon. Many thanks for your response. I just thought and did it already. The fact is that Zabbix accepts inquiries and so {"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"} and so {"groupid": "2"},{ "groupid": "8"}. It's strange, and confused me, because Colleges said what exactly is needed and that's how they do all their life as {"groupid": "2", "groupid": "8"}.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict` as an intermediate structure for your data:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

src=[("groupid", "2"), ("groupid", "8")]

dst = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in src:
    dst[k].append(v)

print(dst)

print(json.dumps(dst))
```

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'groupid': ['2', '8']})
{"groupid": ["2", "8"]}
```

Now that you can shift `json` <-> `defaultdict`, you can also translate `defaultdict` <-> `other`, where other may suit your current application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not quite fit this. I edited the question, because I did not set it clear. I need exactly json with the same keys

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID values cannot be the same, why not inverse the dictionary. E.g.

```
a = {"2": "groupid", "8": "groupid"}
```

A dictionary cannot have the same key, but all the values can be the same.