# python 3 paste text without indent

Tags: python, python-3.x

i used "json" to copy dict from "fixer.io" and copy to text file  , But indent without writes. i want to paste with  indent

```
import requests,json
r = requests.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=f9cd762a9bbdf7da0abe6b3a49c62060&format=1')


with open('irakli.json.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(r.json()))
```

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file/37795053#37795053) answers your question.

Comment: can you give me Stephen's questions ? i can't see