# Creating a JSON file from JSON response data in Python

Tags: python, json, file, python-requests, python-3.6

I want to take the json response data from a REST request and create an actual json file. I tried something like this, but it did not work. Essentially, it just prints the headers. Any suggestions?

```
params = {'f': 'json', 'where': '1=1', 'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPolygon', 'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects','outFields': '*', 'returnGeometry': 'true'}
r = requests.get('https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer/3/query', params)

cslfJson = r.json()
path = r"C:/Workspace/Sandbox/ScratchTests/cslf.json"
file = open(path, 'w')
for line in cslfJson:
    file.write(line + "\r\n")

file.close()
```

Comment: have a look at json.dump

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `json` module

```
my_data = json.loads(r.json())
# my_data is a dict mapping the JSON

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_data, f)
```

if you want, you can print in pretty way using the indent parameter

```
json.dump(my_data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: OK, I just tried `cslfJson = json.loads(r.json())` which creates a dictionary, then I used `with open(path, 'w') as f: json.dump(cslfJson, f, indent=2)`. I got the following error - `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'`.

Comment: This is a bit pointless. There's no reason to load the JSON only to dump it back to a file. Just save the response content directly.

Comment: You are right. It makes sense only if you want to pretty print