# JSON writing to a file error, Extra data: line 1 column 2347 (char 2346)

Tags: python, json

```
    import json
    import requests

    response = requests.get('SOME_LINK_THAT_IVE_REMOVED')

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        pass

    #print (response.text)

    with open('stats.json', 'w') as output:
         json.dump(response.json(), output, indent = 4)                      

what it printed:
```

> {"sessionid":"F9269D5D-2B5C-432B-B8BC-34F87F790619","game_clock_display":"02:12.84","game_clock":132.8432,"game_status":"playing","possession":[0,2],"teams":[{"players":[{"name":"Nooth","playerid":2,"position":[-8.6900005,-0.28800002,-8.6470003],"stats":{"possession_time":22.589041,"points":0,"saves":0,"goals":0,"stuns":3,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":0},"userid":658915067565875,"possession":false},{"name":"erikmelkumyan","playerid":3,"position":[-0.72400004,1.7060001,-28.595001],"stats":{"possession_time":9.5638027,"points":0,"saves":0,"goals":0,"stuns":3,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":1},"userid":2126518170756015,"possession":false},{"name":"Sandman187_","playerid":4,"position":[-2.3990002,2.3380001,-26.783001],"stats":{"possession_time":27.565685,"points":0,"saves":1,"goals":0,"stuns":4,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":1},"userid":1611289978936588,"possession":true}],"team":"BLUE
>   TEAM","possession":true,"stats":{"points":0,"possession_time":59.718529,"interceptions":0,"blocks":0,"steals":0,"catches":0,"passes":0,"saves":1,"goals":0,"stuns":10,"assists":0,"shots_taken":2}},{"players":[{"name":"MooneyWhy","playerid":0,"position":[-4.539,1.399,-13.481001],"stats":{"possession_time":14.364853,"points":2,"saves":1,"goals":0,"stuns":7,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":1,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":1},"userid":1265147863612788,"possession":false},{"name":"b-love","playerid":1,"position":[-11.484,2.072,0.70500004],"stats":{"possession_time":50.680099,"points":6,"saves":1,"goals":0,"stuns":1,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":1},"userid":1457786340976218,"possession":false},{"name":"onikaze","playerid":5,"position":[-7.6980004,1.268,-11.036],"stats":{"possession_time":17.629295,"points":0,"saves":0,"goals":0,"stuns":6,"passes":0,"catches":0,"steals":0,"blocks":0,"interceptions":0,"assists":0,"shots_taken":2},"userid":1636331273057819,"possession":false}],"team":"ORANGE
>   TEAM","possession":false,"stats":{"points":8,"possession_time":82.674248,"interceptions":0,"blocks":0,"steals":1,"catches":0,"passes":0,"saves":2,"goals":0,"stuns":14,"assists":0,"shots_taken":4}}]}
>
> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\Kai\Desktop\Python\testv4.py", line 19, in <module>
>         json.dump(response.json(), output, indent = 4)
>       File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> ```
>
> line 897, in json
>               return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
>             File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json__init__.py",
>   line 348, in loads
>               return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>             File "C:\Users\Kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py",
>   line 340, in decode
>               raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>           json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2347 (char 2346)

Any help? Seems to create invalid JSON file in the text file.

Creates a NULL value on the end of the JSON files when viewed in NotePad++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Comment: are you sure the link response is a json?

Comment: Please reduce that code to a [mcve], there's too much guessing and too little information in what you provide.