# How to write 2d list to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write the contents of 2d list in a specific pattern that needs to be read by another file too. After writing the code, The text file mess up. Help me out from this issue.Thanks

I have tried using a loop to write the contents to text file but I failed.

```
list_final=[['Harry Potter', 'JK Rowling', '55', '2'], ['Start With Why', 'Simon Sinek', '42', '1.5'], ['P With Python', 'John Smith', '40', '1.5']]

file_contain_db_write = open("books.txt", "w")
for each in list_final:
    file_contain_db_write.write(str(", ".join(str(each))))
    file_contain_db_write.write("\n")
file_contain_db_write.close()
```

My expected result:

[image]

My code output:

[image]

Comment: Hello, please post results as text.

Comment: You could use JSON as a common data format. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file).

Comment: [, ', H, a, r, r, y,  , P, o, t, t, e, r, ', ,,  , ', J, K,  , R, o, w, l, i, n, g, ', ,,  , ', 5, 5, ', ,,  , ', 2, ', ]
[, ', S, t, a, r, t,  , W, i, t, h,  , W, h, y, ', ,,  , ', S, i, m, o, n,  , S, i, n, e, k, ', ,,  , ', 4, 2, ', ,,  , ', 1, ., 5, ', ]
[, ', P,  , W, i, t, h,  , P, y, t, h, o, n, ', ,,  , ', J, o, h, n,  , S, m, i, t, h, ', ,,  , ', 4, 0, ', ,,  , ', 1, ., 5, ', ]

Comment: actually, it's a college project. The guideline says us to write in a text file. So, I can't use JSON in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of both `str` calls.  The inner one produces Python’s representation of a list rather than using its contents, and the outer one is being applied to something that is already a string.  (Try testing small pieces of your code in the REPL to avoid these issues.)

Comment: Also, Python docs encourages you to use `with` blocks when handling files