# How to read in .txt file (corpus) into torchtext in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

How to read in .txt file (corpus) into torchtext in pytorrch?

I only see data.Dataset for example datasets and data.TabularData for csv, json, and tsv.

https://github.com/pytorch/text#data

https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#dataset

It still works if I read it in using a Tabular dataset like this:
    `test_file = data.TabularDataset(path=input_filepath, format='csv', fields=[('text', data.Field())])`

But my dataset is not tabular, so I wanted to check to see if there was a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing up a quick script to read your corpus and dump it to JSON (there are [plenty](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/) [of](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-open-file-how-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line/) [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) [out](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)), then use that JSON with torchtext. You're going to want to have some sort of structure to your data to get the most out of torchtext (think batches/iterable datasets).

If you are lost on how to iterate through a dataset, check out [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587198/how-can-i-load-a-dataset-into-a-pytorch-torchtext-data-tabulardataset-from-a-jso/69791954#69791954).