# Write to a json file in particular format in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I need to write the outputs to a json file in python.
I have tried some of the answers here to write to a json file but for some reason I am not finding the correct format I need the data written to a json file.

What I am looking at is:

```
{
  {
  "Region": "BD",
  "name": "bdfe",
  "tyl": "cya",
  "ice": "messi",
  "fed": "bet",
   },
   {
  "Region": "Toron",
  "name": "Cana",
  "tyl": "cyab",
  "ice": "feed",
  "fed": "not",
   },
  ...

}
```

How can I write in this format in python?

Thank you

Comment: Question not clear enough, are you looking to write a list/set of dicts from python to a file in a json format ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your 'json' is wrong. I'm assuming the outer curly brackets should be square brackets and you thus trying to save a list. Sets are not part of the json format. 
Assuming [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309296/1035279) is not what you want because the output is not formatted, you can use [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to format the file as you need it. For example:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Nov 21 2018, 10:19:24) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import json                                                                                            

In [2]: obj = [{ 
   ...:   "Region": "BD", 
   ...:   "name": "bdfe", 
   ...:   "tyl": "cya", 
   ...:   "ice": "messi", 
   ...:   "fed": "bet", 
   ...:    }, 
   ...:    { 
   ...:   "Region": "Toron", 
   ...:   "name": "Cana", 
   ...:   "tyl": "cyab", 
   ...:   "ice": "feed", 
   ...:   "fed": "not", 
   ...:    }]                                                                                                  

In [3]: with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile: 
   ...:     json.dump(obj, outfile, indent=4) 
   ...:                                                                                                        

In [4]: !cat data.json                                                                                         
[
    {
        "Region": "BD",
        "name": "bdfe",
        "tyl": "cya",
        "ice": "messi",
        "fed": "bet"
    },
    {
        "Region": "Toron",
        "name": "Cana",
        "tyl": "cyab",
        "ice": "feed",
        "fed": "not"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replicating that code in python is very simple. All you have to do is convert that to a dictionary. Here is the converted output:

```
import json


mydict = [{
"Region": "BD",
"name": "bdfe",
"tyl": "cya",
"ice": "messi",
"fed": "bet",
 },
 {
"Region": "Toron",
"name": "Cana",
"tyl": "cyab",
"ice": "feed",
"fed": "not",
 }]

with open('data.json', 'w') as out: 
    json.dump(mydict, out, indent = 2)
```

Comment: That is so descriptive. Thx.

Comment: @XilpexThank you, but how do I write this to a json file?

Comment: @LohmarASHAR had misunderstood the question, and am sorry for that. I have edited it to fit the question.

Comment: I meant I had. Srry.

Comment: I couldn't edit the question because of the 5 minutes not edit rule.