# Python stroing data with JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm doing a python "project" for my class! Like I want to make the computer choose random students who to sit with and where! Well... I know how to do it my self, but i want to make it automated with JSON. Uhm.. like when i run the command and then the computer randomly chooses two students and I want to store that choice with JSON, so when i run the command again to check for the other students it wont try to choose the ones that have been already chosen before and that are stored in JSON file.

```py
import random

#whotositwith
names1 = ('')
names2 = ('')
whotositwith = (random.choice(names1) + " - " + random.choice(names2))
bankcouple = whotositwith

#wheretosit
banka = '1'
nxenesit_numer = ('')
wheretosit = ("Nxënësit numër " + random.choice(nxenesit_numer) + " në bankën e " + banka)
banka = wheretosit
print(bankcouple)
```

Don't mind the language, it is not fully in English! :)

Comment: You can `open` a file and use `json.dump(obj, fp)` to store your obj's json representation to that file

Comment: Can you show me an example using the code above?^^

Comment: Ummm... this is taking long xD. Do you have a discord? If you do add me Pan!cKk#6666 and lets talk there! 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
import json
myObj = {'prop1': 130, 'prop2': "bob"}
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(myObj, fp)
```

**EDIT**: That will save `myObj` to `myfile.txt` in json format.

**UPDATE**: If you want to read the json you can do it as follows:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as fp:
    myObj = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: Thanks! What i wanna do now is that when i run the random.choice command to make the code skip what it has chosed if it is already stored in... example: myfile.txt

Comment: @PanicKk I've updated my answer to read a `json` file into an `object`

Comment: I got it!
Now it reads and gets stored in the file but when i re run it, it just updates it, it doesn't add a new line with the new choice!
How to make it store it all not update that one!?

Comment: @PanicKk when you load the json modify it (e.g., add the choice) and then write the modified object back to disk.