# how to Adding list values into a JSON file

Tags: python, json

How to add list values into a JSON file. Here is my code :

```
import os,string
drives_a = [chr(x) + ':' for x in range(65, 90) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ':')]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score -2):

Does this work for you?

```
import json

lst = [1,2,3]
file_name = 'test.json'
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(lst))
```

Comment: It is a low-quality question that does not show any effort and the problem that can be solved with a little googling.