# Write python variables with their names to json file

Tags: python, json

I'm writing python variables to json file and I want to include their name with them.

```
f_name= 'first name'
l_name= 'last name'

import json
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(f_name+' '+ l_name)
```

output in json file :

```
first name last name
```

I want the output to be like this

```
[
  {
    "f_name": "first name",
    "l_name": "last name"
  }
]
```

Comment: You import json, but where do you use it? Need a [mcve].

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Comment: @Barmar It was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the list of dictionaries, and then use https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump to write it into the file

```
import json

f_name= 'first name'
l_name= 'last name'

#Create the list of dictionary
result = [{'f_name': f_name, 'l_name': l_name}]

import json
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    #Write it to file
    json.dump(result, f)
```

The content of the json file would look like

```
[{"f_name": "first name", "l_name": "last name"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create the data structure that you want (in your case, a list containing a dictionary), and call `json.dump()`.

```
with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump([{"f_name": f_name, "l_name": l_name}], f)
```

Don't use `wb` mode when creating a JSON file. JSON is text, not binary.