# How do I change the value of a nested key inside a json file?

Tags: python, json, kivy

I want to change the value of a nested key but I get this error

```
key['score'] = new_score # come back to this
 TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Here is my code:

```
def add_score(self, obj):
        for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
            name = child.text

            with open("streak.json", "r+") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)

            for key in data.keys():
                if key == name:
                    score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')
                    new_score = score + 1
                    key['score'] = new_score # come back to this
```

This is what my json file looks like:

```
{"one": {"action": "one", 
        "delay": 1557963534.4314187, 
        "seconds": 60, 
        "score": 0, 
        "delta": 1557963474.4314187}, 
 "two": {"action": "two", 
         "delay": 1557963664.037102, 
         "seconds": 120, 
         "score": 0, 
         "delta": 1557963544.037102}, 
 "three":{"action": "three", 
          "delay": 1557963792.4683638, 
          "seconds": 180, 
          "score": 0, 
          "delta": 1557963612.4683638}
}
```

How would I change the `score` value inside of my json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, you are iterating over keys array which is `['one','two','three']` in your case.

Try below code. Hope this will help!

```
for key,value in data.items():
    if key == name:
        score = value['score']       
        new_score = score + 1
        value['score'] = new_score
```

Or for one liner instead of for loop use below,

```py
data[name]['score']+=1  #name='one'
```

**Edit within file**

```py
with open('streak.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data[name]['score']+=1 
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: The value of `score` in my json file doesn't change.

Comment: @yemi.JUMP That is because you are reading/parsing the JSON file and storing data into a variable and after that performing operation on that variable not in the file.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear with my question. I have edited my post to include that I want the file to change.

Comment: Your original question and code supplied didn't mention writing to a file.

Comment: @bkyada although this method works, every value with the name score is changed. Is there a way to only have one `score` change?

Comment: @yemi.JUMP Can you be more clear about the use case? If you can provide an example. Here, your outer loop is getting all the names and based on comparison it is updating the score. To change one `score` change do you have any other requirement to check?

Comment: The name of the key is the same as the name of the button, that’s why I did `name=child.text` but it’s updating all of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update the dictionary element directly.

Replace the following

```
for key in data.keys():
    if key == name:
        score = data.get(key, {}).get('score')
        new_score = score + 1
        key['score'] = new_score # come back to this
```

with

```
data[name]['score'] += 1
```

So code would be

```
def add_score(self, obj):
        for child in reversed(self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children):
            name = child.text

            with open("streak.json", "r+") as read_file:
                data = json.load(read_file)

            data[name]['score'] += 1
```

Comment: I need to keep the `if key == name:` protion of the code because the program wont know what `key` is and when I make my code: `key[name]['score'] += 1` I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Just confirming you replaced the 5 lines with my suggested fix?

Comment: when I do that I get ` NameError: name 'key' is not defined`

Comment: apologies, typo at my end. I've updated the answer to use data not key

Comment: The value of `score` in my json file still doesn't change.

Comment: You need to write the updated dictionary back to the file.  You can confirm the dictionary is updated with print data[name]['score']      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
with open("a.json", "r+") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    data[name]['score'] += 1 # update score

with open("a.json", "w") as json_file: #write it back to the file
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Comment: The value of score in my json file doesn't change.

Comment: For that, you will have to write the "data" back to the file. Use json.dump()