# Creating a file of json objects from a list of dicts

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries in python as follows:

```
A = {}
A["name"] = "Any_NameX"
A["age"] = "Any_AgeX"
A["address"] = {"city": "New York", "State": "NY"}

B = {}
B["name"] = "Any_NameY"
B["age"] = "Any_AgeY"
B["address"] = {"city": "Orlando", "State": "FL"}

list_of_dicts.append(A)
list_of_dicts.append(B)
```

Now I write them to a file as follows :

```
for d in list_of_dicts:
    f.write(d)
```

In the file all my double quotes get converted to single quotes

If i do `f.write(json.dumps(d))` everything becomes a string with the backslash character added , but i don't want this , I want to retain them as JSON objects in the file.

If i do `f.write(json.loads(json.dumps(d)))` its the same as writing the dict and everything is in single quotes .

I want a file of json objects one per line all with double quotes. What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you give an example about what is in your file and what do you want in your file. Your question is not clear for me.

Comment: If you dump to json file correctly, It should automatically have double quotes, since json doesn't support single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)

Comment: Also, don't do f.write(...). Use json.dump() directly (not json.dumps which is for dumping to strings rather than files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `json.dump()` (without the `s` in the function name!) with a file object.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

A = {}
A["name"] = "Any_NameX"
A["age"] = "Any_AgeX"
A["address"] = {"city": "New York", "State": "NY"}

B = {}
B["name"] = "Any_NameY"
B["age"] = "Any_AgeY"
B["address"] = {"city": "Orlando", "State": "FL"}

list_of_dicts = [A, B]

with open('json.file', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_of_dicts, f, indent=4)
```

Results in

```
[
    {
        "name": "Any_NameX",
        "age": "Any_AgeX",
        "address": {
            "State": "NY",
            "city": "New York"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Any_NameY",
        "age": "Any_AgeY",
        "address": {
            "State": "FL",
            "city": "Orlando"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: the inner dict (address) becomes like this if i do the above :

"address": {
       "\State\" : \"FL\"
}..
how to remove the escape chaarcters ?

Comment: How do you open/view the file? Which python interpreter do you use on which operating system?