# remove quotes from a json file using python

Tags: python

the dataframe 'dataset' is automatically generated by PowerBI here is the result of my `dataset.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',', index=False)`

```
coordinates,status
"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]",not started
"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]",not started
"[143.4865264,-34.7562088]",not started
"[143.4865286,-34.7562818]",not started
"[143.4865305,-34.7563453]",not started
"[143.4865327,-34.7564183]",not started
"[143.486535,-34.756494]",not started
"[143.4865371,-34.756567]",not started
"[143.486539,-34.7566304]",not started
"[143.4865412,-34.7567034]",not started
```

then to get the json

i do this `data=dataset.to_json(orient='records')`

which give me this results

```
[{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"},
```

how i get this instead , no quotes on the coordinates values

```
[{"coordinates":[143.4865219,-34.7560602],"status":"not started"},{"coordinates":[143.4865241,-34.7561332],"status":"not started"},
```

edit

```
 print(type(data))

<class 'str'>
```

Comment: OK, see my updated answer!

Comment: see edit, i added print(type(data))

Comment: much better, how  to save the final results as a json file ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself.[...]

Your data seems to be a string, and not a list as Python would print it (it uses single quotes by default, the double quotes in your data seem to indicate that it is a string, ready to be saved in a json file for example). So, you have to convert it first to a Python object with [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
from ast import literal_eval
import json

data = """[{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"}]"""
data = json.loads(data)

for d in data:
    d['coordinates'] = literal_eval(d['coordinates'])

print(data)
# [{'coordinates': [143.4865219, -34.7560602], 'status': 'not started'}, {'coordinates': [143.4865241, -34.7561332], 'status': 'not started'}]
```

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: It's probably because your data is a string, and not a list as presented in your question. How are you reading your data?

Answer (score 4):

```py
import json

s = '[{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"}]'
d = json.loads(s)
d[0]['coordinates'] = json.loads(d[0]['coordinates'])
```

Applying this concept to every value can be done as in

```py
for dic in d:
    for key, value in dic.items():
         try:
              temp = json.loads(value)
              if isinstance(temp, list):
                  dic[key] = temp
         except Exception:
              pass
```

or if you are sure there will be a `coordinates` key in ever dictionary
and that key having a "list" value

```py
for dic in d: dic['coordinates'] = json.loads(dic['coordinates'])
```

Comment: maybe show how to do this for all records? this only currently does it for the first record in the blob

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the third code, so you can try it again.

Answer (score -1):

simply u can use eval function.

```
new =[]


l =  '[{"coordinates":"[143.4865219,-34.7560602]","status":"not started"},{"coordinates":"[143.4865241,-34.7561332]","status":"not started"}]'
l=eval(l)
for each_element in l:
    temp={}
    for k,v in each_element.items():
          if k =='coordinates' :
              temp[k]=eval(v)
          else:
               temp[k]=v
     new.append(temp)
print(temp)
```

Comment: Using `eval` is generally discouraged, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice . Iterating on all keys and items of the dict in order to find one key is extremely inefficient. Dicts exist to provide direct access to data without having to iterate, even under the hood, so just use `temp['coordinates'] = ...`. Also, if some part of the data lacks coordinates, your code would silently ignore it. It would be better for it to fail with an exception, or to include some special treatment in a `try ... except` block.