# Convert output to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3

I have list of files from S3 which I am reading using following. Here I have list of files(keys). I would like to further transfer these outputs to JSON files for each individual key from S3.

I am not finding the ideal way to do so. Could you recommend how I can achieve that.

```
import json
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import gzip

try:
     s3 = session.resource('s3')
     key='00604T143000Z_20200604T143500Z.log.gz'
     obj = s3.Object('my_bucket',key)
     n = obj.get()['Body'].read()
     gzipfile = BytesIO(n)
     gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile)
     content = gzipfile.read()
     print(content)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Well try this

```
import json
with open("file.json" , "w") as file:
    json.dump(Data, file)
```

Data must be a dictionary I believe

For more on json

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

For more on dictionaries

[https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary#:~:text=Python%20dictionary%20is%20an%20unordered,when%20the%20key%20is%20known](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary#:%7E:text=Python%20dictionary%20is%20an%20unordered,when%20the%20key%20is%20known).