# How to write JSON post body to a file in Python

Tags: python, json, output

I am new to Python and open system technology. I am developing a http server in python which will be receiving a HTTP POST request from a TPF system in JSON format.
I am trying to test my python server from POSTMAN where I send sample JSON POST request to the localhost:8000 running on my machine , what I want is to take the JSON POST body and write to a file.

I have below code which will read the JSON POST body and send back the same response to the client however I am not able to figure out how do I dump same response to the file provided by user:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime
import os.path
import json




class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        print('this is PNR compare service Response')
        infi = input("enter the name of the file (.json extension) to save  compare result : ")
        infi = os.path.normpath(infi)
        fi = open(infi,'a+')
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime(" %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S\n")
        fi.write('this is PNR compare service Response at' + dt_string)
                
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()      
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'This is POST request. ')
        response.write(b'Received: ')
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())
        #json.dump(body,fi)  
        #json.dump(response.getvalue(),fi)
        #json.dump(response.getvalue(),fi)
        fi.close()



httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Since my response is Byte format, json.dump fails/takes exception (Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable) because it expects a JSON string. Is there any simple way to directly get JSON body from POST request ? My post request is going to be extremely heavy and will have very large JSON body, so looking for a efficient way to parse and dump the response into the file .

Comment: You are already receiving a JSON object. You want to *decode* it with `json.loads`, not *encode* it with `json.dump`.

Comment: thank you ! worked!! :)  data = json.loads(body)   json.dump(data,fi)

Comment: You don't have to decode it *at all*, if you are simply going to immediately re-encode it.

Answer (score 1):

here by [example answer](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/):

```
import json

data = {}
data['people'] = []
data['people'].append({
    'name': 'Larry',
    'website': 'google.com',
    'from': 'Michigan'
})
data['people'].append({
    'name': 'Tim',
    'website': 'apple.com',
    'from': 'Alabama'
})

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

*You might also try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file).*

Answer (score 0):

thank you , I somehow managed to do this by below code ( literal_eval and json.dumps then write to file as string), however , i am sure there are better ways to do this, i will keep exploring it further. Thank you All.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime
import os.path
from ast import literal_eval
import json

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print('this is PNR compare service Response')
        infi = input("enter the name of the file (.json extension) to save  compare result : ")
        infi = os.path.normpath(infi)
        fi = open(infi,'a+')
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime(" %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S\n")
        fi.write('\nthis is PNR compare service Response at' + dt_string)
                
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()      
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(b'This is POST request. ')
        response.write(b'Received: ')
        response.write(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())

        data = literal_eval(body.decode('utf8'))
        #s = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        s = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
        fi.write(s)
        #json.dump(data,fi)
        
        fi.close()


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```