# How to write JSON to file with null values in python?

Tags: python

{"1":null, "2":false, "3":true}

I don't need them to be converted to None False True.

Comment: Have you tried `json.dump`/`json.dumps`

Comment: there is no clarity in the question neither it shows what you have tried

Comment: null is not defined in python, you have to convert it to "None"

Answer (score 6):

According to this page https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

The python None Type is converted to null that you're looking for

| Python | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| dict | Object |
| list | Array |
| tuple | Array |
| str | String |
| int | Number |
| float | Number |
| True | true |
| False | false |
| None | null |

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(r"D:\microsoft presentation\json.json", 'w+') as outfile:
     json.dump(output, outfile, sort_keys = False, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20776329/13226851