# How to retrieve "values" against specific "key" in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a json file that looks like this JSON_FILE:
[image: JSON_FILE]

It contains nested dictionary. I want to retrieve the key **annotations**(appears one time in file). Specifically all the **values** against key **image_id**(appears many times in file) and store it in a separate file. How do I do it in **PYTHON**

Comment: please make an attempt before asking for help.

Comment: writing json to file has [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12309269/3462319)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this

```
import json
    
with open("myfile.json") as f:
  data_retreived= json.load(f) 
a=data_retreived["annotations"]
    
    
        
myfile = open('data.txt', 'w') 
for f in a:   
  myfile.write("%s\n" % f['image_id'])   
  #print(f['image_id']) 
myfile.close()
```