# Python - replace integer in json body

Tags: python, json

I need to replace an integer in a json body:

```
file1.json
{
    "id": 0,
    "col_1": "some value",
    "col_2": "another value"
}
```

I know to replace a string, I would use:

```
import json

with open('file1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data["col_1"] = data["col_1"].replace("some value", "new value")
```

But how would I replace the `id`, to the number 5 for example?

Comment: ... `data['id'] = 5`

Comment: Why would you even use `data["col_1"].replace("some value", "new value")` and not `data["col_1"] = "new value"`?

Comment: sorry guys, I need more coffee I think.  The answer seems obvious.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea! Loading in the json as a string with json.load(path) and then manipulating the data in the instance is certainly the easiest way to do it. As the comments said, you can set that value with `data["Column name"] = new value` since once the data is read into python it's held as a dictionary.

What you need to do then is *save* the manipulated data item to .json, IIRC the function you're looking for is json.dump

I found a related post here: [How do I write JSON data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file)